# How do I change the search key length?

Tags: 7, search

I'm using Search API and Fuzzysearch in D7, and it's unable to search for three letter words. Unfortunately, we have a TON of 3-letter acronyms at work, so these need to be searchable. I've looked in the Search API and Fuzzysearch settings, but can't see where to change the length of the search keys.

I get the following error message when searching:

> The following search keys are too short or too common and were
>   therefore ignored: "api".

Answer (score 2):

go to `admin/config/search/settings` and change the length of Minimum word length to index to `2` and re-index the site.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Thanks. I'm using search_api, and I finally found where that setting was. I was looking in "Default fuzzysearch index", which seemed to make sense to me. But no, it was in "Default fuzzysearch server". Never occurred to me to look there, since I was wanting to change the index settings.